# how to correct overlaping text in base R plots

Tags: r, plot

just wonder how to correct overlapping texts in base R plots.
below are the code and the figure.

```
plot(countdata,
        col= "blue",
        main = "Before batch correction",
        cex = 1.5,
        cex.lab = 2,
        cex.main = 2,
        cex.axis = 2,
        xlab = "PC1:58%",
        ylab = "PC2:6%")
```

[image]

Comment: What would you like to do with the overlapping text? Remove it? Dodge it? There are no associated points, so presumably doding the labels would put them in the wrong position.

Comment: I want to to see them separated from each other.

Comment: perhaps add some random noise with `runif`?